# jQuery link expand

Tags: jquery, text, expand

I need a little help on link expand effect.

Please look this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LxRHa/

Guys on flash recognize this effect easily so.. matter is I have language links shortened by 2 initials p.s. En (for english) in fiddle when you hover that link it fades and shows English fully. I made it with fades but it's not smooth. I need the right effect solution for this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote up a quick script based off of your description. A JSFiddle can be found here - http://jsfiddle.net/68YsH/. 
​

Comment: xthexder's script works, but unfortunately is not flexible. In mine, you can add as many anchor tags with the desired language you want and it will get the exact width of the collapsed and expanded element.

Answer (score 4):

I was just playing around with this and I came up with this transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/VkWdd/

It may or may not suit your needs, since at the moment it's tuned for words the length of English. You may be able to modify it to do what you want.

Comment: After some tests found a little bit buggy try to sweep between links while the other links effect is being done the other one get affected in my code... Austin's code is just perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help with the concept at least =)

Answer (score 1):

This is more dynamic
**[take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkWdd/4/)**

Comment: yes, I was playing with it too but suddenly I saw you already answered it, just added my logic with your code. Did you mind ?

Comment: Nah, Open source makes stuff better =D

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery:

```
$(function() {

    $(".languages a").hover( 
        function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(150, function(){
                $(this).html('English').fadeIn(250);
            })
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150, function(){
                $(this).html('En').fadeIn(250);
            });
        }

    );

});​
```